# How to create a completely shared Unix directory?

Tags: permissions, chmod

I want to share a directory among 2 users on my system. Here is what I have done so far:

I have users "user1" and "user2". I created a group called "ours" and added both users to the group. I also created a /ours directory and set it to the "ours" group:

```
drwxrwsr-x user1 ours 4096 dec 13 2020 /ours
```

Now, things mostly work, but sometimes when we create files in this folder the file will not be owned by the "ours" group. For example, I just downloaded a PDF to that folder, and I see that the PDF file is set as user "user1" and group "user1" instead of group "ours" (to be honest I don't remember if the file was effectively created by Firefox or Evince there). This is annoying, because whenever I want the other person to really access the files I have to run 'chown -R' on the dir to make everything be owned by the ours group.

How can I make sure files created there by the various different programs we use will always be owned by the "ours" group? I thought the group 's' permission (setgid) would enforce that, but that's not what I'm seeing after using the dir for a while. Are user space programs chgrp-ing the files they create there?

If that's not possible, what exactly would you suggest I do to have a completely seamless "shared directory" experience?

Thanks.

Comment: First, which flavour of Unix? (Are you using Linux? FreeBSD? macOS? Solaris? AT&T System V?) Second, which filesystem type are the files stored on?

Comment: SetGID is the ticket. I use it on Samba shares all the time. not a lot we can tell you about other programs impacting that directory, but I wouldn't expect most apps to be chowning stuff on the regular.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the directory as setgid should enforce the files created there being owned by the group, but yes, it is possible that some programs are chgrp-ing the file.

In that case, I don't see other method than setting up a cron job that periodically (eg. every 10 minutes) does `chgrp -R` on the directory.